# Centering UML diagrams in MetaUML

Tags: horizontal-alignment, luatex, metauml

I'm using LuaTex to draw some UML diagrams in MetaUML. The diagrams appear left align in the page. How do I center them?

I tried \centering before the mplibcode environment and also tried enclosing the environment in center environment. But did not work.

Comment: I know you have found the answer, but even so a small [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would enhance your question.  (And the answer...)

Comment: Okay. I will add it to the question and answer

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution. 
Adding `\mplibforcehmode` makes `\centering` work for `mplibcode` environments.

> `\mplibforcehmode` When this macro is declared, every mplibcode figure box will be type- set in horizontal mode, so \centering, \raggedleft etc will have effects. \mplibnoforcehmode, being default, reverts this setting. (Actually these commands redefine \prependtomplibbox. You can define this command with anything suitable before a box.)

[Source](https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib/luamplib.pdf)